# Clairauts "equality of mixed partial derivatives" theorem (interpretation)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

So I know how to prove this theorem via limits or whatever and I'm okay with that.

What I'm not okay with is the interpretation. I just can't visualise how this is true in 3d space, any ideas? How do you guys interpret this theorem?

My guess is that this theorem is implying that change looks the same from all directions. But even if this is true, I would like to know how this can be visualised.

Or tell me if this is really not important and I should just trust what the theorem says?

Thanks

Comment: What theorem are you talking about?

Comment: f xy = f yx

      .......yx and xy are notations for partial derivatives in case you are wondering and f is the original function.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives

Comment: It's not that easy to notice just by looking that there is something strange about a function where $f_{xy}\neq f_{yx}$ (at a single point). See here, for example: http://stanwagon.com/wagon/mathimages/HTMLLinks/mathimages_6.html

Comment: Whaaat. Why aren't they equal in this case? I thought this equality always held true if the function is continuous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roughly speaking, derivatives are "very small increments" of functions: 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\approx \frac{f(x+\epsilon, y)-f(x, y)}{\epsilon}=\frac{\Delta_x f}{\epsilon},$$
and
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \approx \frac{f(x, y+\epsilon)-f(x, y)}{\epsilon}=\frac{\Delta_y f}{\epsilon}.$$
Now clearly $\Delta_x\Delta_y f=\Delta_y\Delta_x f$. Therefore, from the relation
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\approx\frac{\Delta_x\Delta_y f}{\epsilon^2}=\frac{\Delta_y \Delta_x f}{\epsilon^2}\approx\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}, $$
one expects that partial derivatives commute as well. That this is not always the case is due to the fact that some continuity is needed in order to pass to the limit and convert the $\approx$ relations into precise identities.

Comment: Ok great. Is my focus in visualisation not worthwhile? I mean I understand the maths you are using, but I still want to visualise this. Should I insist on this or is it useless at this point? Thanks!

Comment: It is hard to tell. In a nutshell: you should insist, but not too much. Visualization is good for you, but in the end, the mathematics you produce are those little symbols you write down on paper. Nobody cares if you got them by visualization or by formal symbol pushing. Moreover, some definitions and some results are hard to completely visualize at first glance, before having used them for a while. So you should pay attention not to obsess on visualization. Anyway, it is up to you. You will craft your personal mathematical style.

Comment: Hey did you know about this? stanwagon.com/wagon/mathimages/HTMLLinks/mathimages_6.html

.Here the derivatives are defined but the equality wont hold true at the origin.

Comment: This is one of the most standard counterexamples showing that equality of partial derivatives might fail without some  assumption. If it is new to you, I recommend you leave the internet for a while and open an old-fashioned book.